# Summing the different values in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I want to sum the different values for each column. i think that i should use a special aggregation using apply() but i don't know the correct code

```py
A  B  C  D  E  F  G
1  2  3  4  5  6  7
1  3  3  4  8  7  7
2  2  3  5  8  1  1
2  1  3  5  7  5  1

#i want to have this result 
for each value in column A

A  B  C  D  E   F   G
1  5  3  4  13  13  7
2  3  3  5  15  6   1
```

Comment: `df.groupby('A').sum()` ?

Comment: @QuangHoang no only non duplicates sum :)

Comment: df.groupeby('A').sum() will sum all values in each element in A, i want to sum just the values if they are different and return the same value if they are equal

Comment: @anky_91 yeah, I see that coming, but it's rather unclear what OP means by *defferent values*. One can change to  `groupby('A').apply(lambda x: x.unique().sum())`.

Comment: @QuangHoang umm, not sure. I was thinking of a mask. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can vectorize this by dropping duplicates per index positions.  You can then re-create the origin matrix conveniently using a sparse matrix.

You could accomplish the same thing create a zero array and adding, but this way you avoid the large memory requirement if your `A` column is very sparse.

---

```
from scipy import sparse

def non_dupe_sums_2D(ids, values):
    v = np.unique(ids)
    x, y = values.shape
    r = np.arange(y)
    m = np.repeat(a, y)
    n = np.tile(r, x)
    u = np.unique(np.column_stack((m, n, values.ravel())), axis=0)
    return sparse.csr_matrix((u[:, 2], (u[:, 0], u[:, 1])))[v].A

a = df.iloc[:, 0].to_numpy()
b = df.iloc[:, 1:].to_numpy()

non_dupe_sums_2D(a, b)
```

```
array([[ 5,  3,  4, 13, 13,  7],
       [ 3,  3,  5, 15,  6,  1]], dtype=int64)
```

***Performance***

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 100, (100, 100)))

a = df.iloc[:, 0].to_numpy()
b = df.iloc[:, 1:].to_numpy()

%timeit pd.concat([g.apply(lambda x: x.unique().sum()) for v,g in df.groupby(0) ], axis=1)
1.09 s ± 9.19 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit df.iloc[:, 1:].groupby(df.iloc[:, 0]).apply(sum_unique)
1.05 s ± 4.97 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit non_dupe_sums_2D(a, b)
7.95 ms ± 30.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

---

***Validation***

```
>>> np.array_equal(non_dupe_sums_2D(a, b), df.iloc[:, 1:].groupby(df.iloc[:, 0]).apply(sum_unique).values)
True
```

Answer (score 2):

Not so ideal, but here's one way with `apply`:

```
pd.concat([g.apply(lambda x: x.unique().sum()) for v,g in df.groupby('A') ], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
    0   1
A   1   2
B   5   3
C   3   3
D   4   5
E  13  15
F  13   6
G   7   1
```

You can certainly transpose the dataframe to obtain the expected output.

Answer (score 2):

I'd do something like:

```
def sum_unique(x):
    return x.apply(lambda x: x.unique().sum())

df.groupby('A')[df.columns ^ {'A'}].apply(sum_unique).reset_index()
```

which gives me:

```
   A  B  C  D   E   F  G
0  1  5  3  4  13  13  7
1  2  3  3  5  15   6  1
```

which seems to be what you're expecting

Comment: @GhaitBoukachab the recommended way of using stackoverflow is to mark the answer you consider the most useful as the "accepted" one